# Does antd support Welsh language

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd date picker. Is there a way to show months and days in date picker in welsh language?

Referred this doc https://ant.design/docs/react/i18n
But couldn't find welsh in it. Is there a way to add welsh in the antd datepicker.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to me that someone needs to create a locale package, as that same page explains.

Answer (score 0):

Ant Design doesn't seem to support Welsh, but you can add it by yourself.

They state [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/i18n#Adding-new-language) how you could add a new language to the datepicker, and they even give you an [example pull request](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/pull/21387/files) so you can know which files to add/change.

The best you could do right now is fork the repo, add support for Welsh, make a PR to the project and while it isn't accepted use your own forked version.